# The usage of "dead eyes"and "the eyes of death"

Tags: meaning, differences, context, emotions

I am thinking about the difference between the usage of "dead eyes" and "the eyes of death". Can someone enlighten me.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I think your question has not been well-received because you have not provided any context— where do these phrases appear? What are the surrounding sentences?— nor any evidence of preliminary research, such as a web search. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of *the eyes of death* is a metaphor for death itself. (To be precise it's a synecdoche, in which the part stands in for the whole.) Consider Northumberland's declaration from Shakespeare's *Richard II* (Act 2, Scene 1):

> even through **the** hollow **eyes of death**, I spy life peering

That is, in the midst of death, life still shows itself.

Or from Byron's *Mazeppa*

> And my dim **eyes of death** had need.
>   No hope arose of being freed.

The protagonist is near death and needs rescue, but he is without hope of such.

The eyes of death may be described by other adjectives such as *fearful* and *ruined*, but these are depictions of death more than the the look in someone's eyes.

The term *dead eyes* finds two uses. The first is to characterize a corpse through the stillness and unfocused nature of its eyes. The second is to describe the look of someone without compassion or indeed any feeling at all. From *[Black Magic: A Modern Arabic Novel](https://books.google.com/books?id=RVLbAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT125&dq=%22dead%20eyes%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiehMTJyb7OAhUK7CYKHXFaCgs4WhDoAQgmMAI#v=onepage&q=%22dead%20eyes%22&f=false)* by Hamdy el-Gazzar (*emphasis* mine):

> She doesn't believe in symbols and she's not horrified by the look in
>   your eyes, your **dead eyes**, *empty of all expression, of
>   everything*.